# How to Onload() set focus to jQuery Handsontable

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onload, handsontable

What is the proper method to set the focus onload to first field in jQuery Handsontable ?

Here is the example link http://jsfiddle.net/4kvMq/4/

```
$(function () {
  $(window).load(function () {
    $('#example10grid table tbody tr td:first-child').focus();
  });
});
```

Even have tried to set focus manually but no luck!

```
$('#btnGo').click(function() {
    $(".dataTable table tbody tr td:first-child").focus();
});
```

Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your request. Now there is a public method to do that.

Use it on a button:

```
$('#btnGo').click(function(event) {
  setTimeout(function() {
      //timeout is needed because Handsontable normally deselects 
      //current cell when you click outside the table
      $("#example10grid").handsontable("selectCell", 0, 0);
  }, 10);
});
```

Or DOM ready:

```
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() { 
      //timeout is needed because Handsontable normally deselects 
      //current cell when you click outside the table
      $("#example10grid").handsontable("selectCell", 0, 0);
  }, 10);
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/warpech/4kvMq/35/

Comment: Thanks. This hack works work fine. I have write in request in [GitHub](https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/issues/21)

Comment: Now there is a method for that: "selectCell". I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. The problem is the way handsontable handles focus events. It binds a click handler to the `hmtl` element and detects every millisecond if your cursor is on the table. Therefore, you can't change the focus with a `click()` or `focus()` on a specific element.

Furthermore, since you can't change the cursor position with JavaScript for security reasons (and jQuery can't trigger click or focus events natively), you can't change the focus on a cell easily. It would only be possible to modify handsontable itself to change the selected table cell.

Comment: Sammy, Thanks for input. Really appreciate it.